# Do I always have to use constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

Do I always have to use constructor in C#?

I am working on some examples. They use constructor. I am not sure if I understand it, because I feel that I don't have to use constructor.

Comment: I `guess` you're referring to parameterized constructors? Your question is completely unclear. You don't "always" have to use anything in particular. There's places where certain things make sense, other places where they don't. What is your question? post the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

If a constructor isn't defined, a *default* constructor is automatically generated for you. The generated code is the same as writing:

```
public MyClass() : base()
{
}
```

If you want parameters, or member initialization, then you will need to write your own. You also need to write one if you inherit from a a base class with parameters. Since you are just learning about constructors, you don't need to worry about it yet, but it is something to keep in mind.

Note that this constructor is removed if you define **any** constructor (even a parameterized one), so you need to explicitly define it if you still want a parameterless one.

Here is the documentation of a default constructor: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not to be rude but you have to give it a try.

A class does not need a constructor (or at least will generate one calling the base classes' matching constructor, if one) unless:

- You want to do some initialisation of variables;
- You want to pass in parameters;
- You need to since the base class doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Clarification: a class will _always_ have a constructor. If you don't write one explicitly, then it will use the default constructor. And you don't _derive_ constructors.

Comment: @gunr2171: I don't think that is entirely true. It does boil down to get the constructor from base classes. It does not generate one for you.

Comment: All classes have constructors even if you don't explicitly define one. A default one will call the default constructor of any base classes.

Comment: I'm going to remove my downvote because of the benefit of the doubt. However, I'm not convinced that a class would "get" a (default) constructor from a base class. Why go all the way to `object`? Why not stop at a higher level? Plus, constructors with the same arguments don't have to match up.

Comment: And I would like to point out the terminology that @Lee said, that a default constructor will _call_ the default/empty constructor of its base class.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and suggestions. I updated the answer a little to incorporate your thoughts. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Just so you know, the MSDN docs do not mention inheriting a constructor, it sounds like it is generated like in C++

Comment: Changed the answer again. Thanks @BradleyDotNET.

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor is created for every class. However you can create your own constructor with or without parameteres.

You should use Constructors when your class for example needs to manipulate an object that it requires.

For example:

```
public class Car
{
    string _model = "";
    public Car(string CarModel)
    {
        this._model = CarModel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of constructor is that if you have some code to execute when the object is created, write it in constructor. **EDIT** Using constructor is not obligatory in C#. For the classes which you create through a wizard, a constructor you will see created by default. But for the class which you create/write, you may create/write constructor.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The question is about including a constructor definition in the code, not what to put in that definition.

Comment: I told the purpose of constructor in simple words. What's wrong? @gunr2171

Comment: Leaving blank is not the same as omitting.

Comment: @Nanosoft the question is "Do I always have to use constructor in C#?". However this answers the question "what do I put in a constructor?"

Comment: Modified the answer. @gunr2171

Comment: `But for the class which you create/write, you have to create/write constructor.` This is incorrect.

Comment: This is getting better. You still don't mention the importance/use of having (or not having) the default constructor, but it isn't glaringly incorrect/not useful, so I have removed my downvote.